# How to get missed/undelivered messages on whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

For some reason I uninstalled WhatsApp. If I reinstall it after a day or two , will I receive those messages which might have been sent to me during this period? If not ,Is it possible to get those messages somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you delete you WhatsApp account, **you should** get at least 2day old messages delivered after you install WhatsApp next time. Congo.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, as soon as you removed/uninstalled WhatsApp from your device, the other people will not be able to see your contact of whatsapp. Hence, they will not be able to send you message anyways. And, of course when you re-installed whatsapp again, they can connect with you too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to get those messages. When you reinstall whatsapp giving your phone number, it asks whether you want to recover your older messages. You have to select Yes. It recovers only upto a certain date.